# JqGrid not showing data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, jqgrid

I create a jqgrid with json string. Just before an hour its working properly. Now its not working i didn't understand the error. It does not show any error message too.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string value = "{\"Table\":[{\"FLD_ID\":1,\"FLD_DATE\":\"17-02-2014 04:51:34 PM\",\"FLD_MOD_DATE\":\"17-02-2014 04:51:43 PM\",\"FLD_CNTRY_NAME\":\"DAFEDA\",\"FLD_CNTRY_CODE\":null,\"FLD_DESC\":\"VALUE\",\"FLD_STATUS\":1,\"CREATED_BY\":\"DAFEDA\"}],\"Table1\":[{\"DBSTATUS\":\"SUCCESS\"}]}";
    context.Response.Write(value);
}

   <script type="text/javascript">
                    try {
                        jQuery.fn.center = function () {
                            this.css("position", "absolute");
                            this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
                            this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
                            return this;
                        }

                        var gwdth = $("#grd").width();
                        jQuery("#JQCntryGrid").jqGrid({
                            url: 'JQGridHandler.ashx',
                            datatype: "json",
                            width: gwdth,
                            height: 'auto',
                            colNames: ['Id', 'Date', 'Mod Date', 'Country Name', 'Country Code', 'Desc', 'Status', 'Created By'],
                            colModel: [
                        { name: 'FLD_ID', index: 'FLD_ID', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                        { name: 'FLD_DATE', index: 'FLD_DATE', width: 150, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: false },
                        { name: 'FLD_MOD_DATE', index: 'FLD_MOD_DATE', width: 60,  editable: false },
                        { name: 'FLD_CNTRY_NAME', index: 'FLD_USER_NAME', width: 150, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { required: true} },
                        { name: 'FLD_CNTRY_CODE', index: 'FLD_CNTRY_CODE', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { required: true} },
                        { name: 'FLD_DESC', index: 'FLD_DESC', width: 130, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { required: true} },
                        { name: 'FLD_STATUS', index: 'FLD_STATUS', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "select", editrules: { required: true} },
                        { name: 'CREATED_BY', index: 'CREATED_BY', width: 130, sortable: true, editable: false },
                      ],......
```

Answer (score 3):

You need add `jsonReader` with `root: "Table"` to solve the problem:

```js
jsonReader: {
    root: "Table",
    repeatitems: false
},
```

I recommend you additionally to use `loadonce: true`, `gridview: true`, `autoencode: true` options (see the documentation). The setting of `width` can be probably be replaced with the usage of `autowidth: true`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3085540.htm) demonstrates the results.